# To calculate Mercator projection of points inside of sphere. What if latitude is more than $90^\circ$?

Tags: logarithms, spherical-coordinates, spheres, conformal-geometry, map-projections

I want to calculate Mercator projection of points inside of sphere.
First, the points are transformed to local system.
Then the latitude and longitude are calculated based on following equations

> $\Large r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\\Large\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac zr=\cos^{-1}\frac{z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\\Large\psi=\tan^{-1}\frac yx$

and the Mercator projection for each point is calculated based on:

> $\Large(x,y)=(\lambda, \ln[\tan(\frac{\phi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4})])$

but it has error in some points because of $\ln$ of negative numbers and when I check the latitudes in these cases, they are more than $90^\circ$. What's wrong?

Comment: Yes but the problem is achieved latitudes are not in range -90 +90

Answer (score 0):

In your second equation, you compute the coordinates $(x,y$) of the projected point, that is, on the planar map. Here $y$ can be negative, but there is no log of a negative value, and latitudes $\varphi\in]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$ (in radians, not degrees) are mapped to $y\in]-\infty,+\infty[$.

The problem lies in your first system of equations. In this system, the $\color{red}{\mathrm{co}}$latitude is $\theta$, and the longitude $\varphi$. In cartography the [longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude) is $\lambda$, and the latitude is $\varphi$, so I will use $\varphi$ for the latitude here.

First, be aware that the notation $\arctan \frac yx$ should really be $\varphi=\mathrm{atan2}(y,x)$ (see the link on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions), where you picked the equations). Here Wikipedia perpetuates a long tradition of incorrectly writing the formula: the correct value of the longitude is *not* $\arctan \frac yx$ in general. *(additional caution: some programming languages write it `atan2(y,x)`, others `atan2(x,y)`, so you will have to check)*

But the problem really is the latitude: in mathematics and physics, it's common to measure the [colatitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colatitude), that is the angle between the $z$ axis and the vector $\vec r$, which is then in $[0,\pi]$: that's what is given on Wikipedia, and it's clearly stated in the article that *"$\theta$ is inclination from the $z$ direction"*. In cartography, you want the [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude), measured from the equator. Here the latitude is $\varphi=\frac\pi2-\theta$.

Comment: Thanks now they are in the range, but I expected weight and height of mercator 2PI and PI, the achieved weight is 2PI but the height isn't, what's the problem?

Comment: @MRezaei There is no problem: if $\varphi$ is exactly $\pi/2$, then you can check that $y=+\infty$. The $y$ values are not bounded. Additionally, the scale is not linear: even if you get $\varphi$ in a smaller interval, say $\varphi\in[-85^\circ,+85^\circ]$, you know the maximum $y$ value corresponds to $85^\circ$, but you can't put a linear scale on your plot to show latitudes. That's why equidistant [parallels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_latitude) are not equidistant on a [Mercator map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

Comment: @MRezaei When you draw a map, you plot data with the transformed $y$, but you show on the axis the original value of $\varphi$.

Comment: I thought the achieved x and y have ranges because of this " The height of the cylinder—and so the height of the map—is
pR, where R is the earth’s radius. The width of the map, when the cylinder is
unrolled so that the map is ﬂat, is twice the height, 2pR"    it's written in the "the science and navigation book"

Comment: so x has range -pi and pi but y is unlimited, right?

Comment: @MRezaei Yes, that's right, $y$ is unlimited. It's also explained on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Derivation_of_the_Mercator_projection). According to the original values of $\varphi$, the total height is indeed $\pi$ (or $\pi R$ if you want to measure distances instead of angles). However this is extremely misleading, as it's completely wrong on the $y$ axis, that is, on the "true" projected map: the "height" $\pi/2$ is at infinity.